# Get Wi-Fi signal strength via libnl?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, wifi

I want to read the Wi-Fi signal strength from a userspace program on Linux.

As `/proc/net/wireless` is not available on the system, I have found out that [libnl](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/) should be used to acquire the information.

Compared to just reading a value in `/proc`, communication via `libnl` seems to be very complicated. I have read various documentation, but I'm still not sure exactly what to do.

Can anyone give an example on how to read the Wi-Fi signal strength via `libnl`?

Comment: A custom kernel built without the WEXT interface as it has long been deprecated. I have been reading the [Core Library Developer's Guide](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have iw library https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git.
You can type **sudo iw dev wlan0 scan** (instead of 'wlan0' interface you can type the one you need) in your terminal. There is **signal** line that I think you are interested in. All the work for getting this information to user is made in **scan.c** file of **iw** library. So you can just check the source code and get some tips from there.